# How to change all mic output to mono from stereo in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, microphone, mono

I have ubuntu 21.04. And no matter which mic I use whether inbuilt mic or external mic all the mic input is only outputted to left channel only. I want to make that my both channel have same output i.e. mono output from my mic. How can I do this?

I have already tried `alsamixer` but It didn't help.

Is there any way that I can make all my mic input to be outputted as mono?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Ubuntu uses Pulseaudio, have a look at the [Pulseaudio modules](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/), and use the [module-remap-source](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-remap-source) to create an additional source with the desired mapping (left channel twice to both left and right channel). There's an example how to use `load-module` with that at the end of the section.

Note that many audio processing programs can deal with a mono source (only one channel), so you may or may not need this mapping, depending on what you want to do with it (you didn't tell us your actual use case).